# In a lottery, there are $200$ losing tickets and $10$ winning tickets. We draw with return untill we get our first win. What's the average before win?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, lotteries

In a lottery, there are $200$ losing tickets and $10$ winning tickets. We draw with return untill we get our first win. How many times on average do we have to draw to win? Write standart deviation from that value.

**Can someone tell me potential reason why I didn't get full points (2 out of 5) for this task with this solution ?
I think its correct 100% so I am confused, could please someone verify?**

Its obvious geometric distribution so I will use formulas related to them:

$p=\frac{10}{210}=\frac{1}{21}$

$q=\frac{200}{210}=\frac{20}{21}$

$E(X)=\frac{1}{p}=21$

$Var(x)=\frac{q}{p^2}=420$

$\sigma=\sqrt{420}$

We have to draw atleast 21 times to win.

Comment: Your final line... "*We have to draw at least 21 times to win* **on average.**"  Those final two words are crucial and can not be skipped.

Comment: @JMoravitz
I wrote solution exactly like I did here, I understand that I forgot 'on average', but there's E(X) value also which by definition should be enough as an answer... Seems too cruel to get -3 points for that, because everything else is fine right? Anyway thanks for checking

Comment: I'd have to see the *exact* wording of both the original question and your response.  There could be subtle mistakes in how you have it transcribed or had interpreted it.  For instance, if you were talking about *number of failures* before first success where we do not include the success in that count versus were we to have included it in the count.  It is possible also that it should have been *without* replacement instead of with.  The instructions might also have insisted on expressing answers as decimal approximations rather than leaving it with square roots.

Comment: If it were truly as written (*both the question and your answer*), I might not have taken anything off.  Maybe half a point for incorrect phrasing at the end, but even then probably not and I would have just written a comment.